# pretty URL's and trailing .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Webforms application using the standard template in VS2012. It uses the standard configuration of:

```
FriendlyUrlSettings settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings {AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent};
aRoutes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

I then also have a site map of:

```
<siteMapNode url="" title="Container"  description="">
    <siteMapNode url="~/Default" title="Dashboard"  description="">
      <siteMapNode url="~/Framework/ChangeLog" title="Change Log"  description="" />
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Account"  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Account/Manage" title="Profile"  description="" />
      </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
```

All this works well until inadvertently I reference say ~/Default.aspx and then naturally this is not picked up by the site map due to the trailing .aspx.

So what is the solution here to strip off trailing ".aspx"? Hopefully this will also give me insight i how to deal with query strings also breaking site navigation when I do something like ~/Framework/ChangeLog?v=1.20

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you set up your IIS to send all requests to ASP.NET engine?